# use SESSION id if GET id is not set or empty

Tags: php, session, if-statement, get

small little question, how would I be able to use my sessions id if the Get id is not set. Here is my small snippet of code.

```
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && intval($_GET['id'])) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];//the user id
    } else {
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];//the user id
    }
```

right now it seems to work fine if the **?id=** isnt set at all, but if its empty it throws off an error

**SQL: select * from users where id= >> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**

i pretty much just want to make it fail proof, that it only would use the ID GET if its an actual link such as **profile_pic.php?id=100** but use session when its **profile_pic.php?id=** or **profile_pic.php?id=apples**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intval` is returning an integer not boolean. If it evaluates in 0 that means false, otherwise true. Don't use it in if.

```
// GET id is set and not empty and is numeric
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
// Else take value from session, if not empty and is numeric
elseif (isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_SESSION['id']);
}
// Something went wrong
else {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('id not set via GET and id not in session or not numeric');
}
```

Comment: Its a pleasure old chap

Comment: it still seems to error when I load a variable such as **profile_pic.php?id=a** or **profile_pic.php?id=** I would like it to then default to the session id since its a area where you have to be logged in to access.

Comment: @DanFromGermany still no luck, is there any other piece of code you want me to show you? it still gives an error if you leave just **profile_pic.php?id=** or if you put a letter.

Comment: When I use **http://website.com/new/profile_pic.php?id=a** it gives the error `SQL: select * from users where id=a >> Unknown column 'a' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I appoligize, I sent that message before you said that haha my bad. Here is the code 

`<?php
$sql="select * from users where id={$id}";
$rs=mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL: ".$sql." >> ".mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($rs);

if($num>0){
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    extract($row);
 ?>`

Comment: You must have put the wrong code in the wrong place. It's impossible, PHP would not use `a` because it's false on `is_numeric`. See codpad: http://codepad.org/oGaDhOsF

Comment: I moved it above a few and it works splendid. does ISSET and EMPTY mean 2 different things?

Comment: Yes. When you use  `profile.php?id=` the `id` isset, but it's empty :)